# Tailwind CSS for ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, npm-install, tailwind-css

I have been going through all kinds of tutorials they are either just straight up not useful or they are using previous versions of `VS` and/or `ASP.NET`.

How do you **install** `tailwind CSS` on an `MVC project`?

I wish they had published the `lib` for everyone to `copy` and `paste` in their resource file and use it freely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do you install tailwind css on a MVC project? I wish they had published the lib for everyone to copy and paste in their resource file and use it freely.

You can try to include tailwind css from CDN, like below.

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Besides, you can try to finding client-side libraries and add the required files to your project through [the Add Client-Side Library dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've created this [package](https://github.com/BamButz/msbuild-tailwindcss) that's adding a new build action.

You simply set the PackageReference and set the build action of your stylesheet to `TailwindCSS`. During the build process, the stylesheet will be converted via PostCSS.

For more details, you can take a look at its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/BamButz/msbuild-tailwindcss).